# What are the drawbacks/problems in factored operating system(fos) for clouds and manycores?

Tags: operating-system, cloud, multicore

I am critically reading a research paper in which authors have presented an operating system for clouds and multicores . What can be the possible drawbacks in this research paper ?? 
Link to paper is 
http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/62570

Answer (score 0):

I think following are some problems

1) The paper talks about only the services. It does not talk anything about the handling of data (or reliability to be precise) in the cloud. So, a data handling system has to be used as a complementary system in order for realizing the performance (By fos) and reliability (By data handling system). Don’t you think, it is a deficiency in the system?

2) If data handling system has to be used, then can the existing data replication techniques or systems like RAID and similar systems be used directly, or they also needs to be changed in order to be compatible to be used on a multicore supporting Operation System?